# `GraphPlot3D` does not preserve the order of points/edges. How to identify coordinates of those points then?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Here is my code.

`data` contains list of edges of a graph. For example the first edge is `5->8` which means the edge has end points `5` and `8`. The order of edges is important for me, although the graph would look the same even if the order of edges was different.

`gr` contains the plot of the graph. You can use `FullForm[gr]` to see what it consists of.

`coordinates` contains coordinates of points extracted form the plot.

`edges` contains edges extracted from the plot.

```
data = {5 -> 8, 8 -> 11, 11 -> 14, 14 -> 17, 17 -> 20, 20 -> 30, 
   30 -> 32, 32 -> 34, 34 -> 36, 36 -> 38, 38 -> 3, 3 -> 6, 6 -> 9, 
   9 -> 12, 12 -> 17, 17 -> 19, 19 -> 21, 21 -> 23, 23 -> 25, 
   25 -> 35, 35 -> 38, 38 -> 1, 1 -> 4, 4 -> 7, 7 -> 10, 10 -> 20, 
   20 -> 22, 22 -> 24, 24 -> 26, 26 -> 28, 28 -> 33, 33 -> 36, 
   36 -> 39, 39 -> 2, 2 -> 7, 7 -> 9, 9 -> 11, 11 -> 13, 13 -> 15, 
   15 -> 25, 25 -> 28, 28 -> 31, 31 -> 34, 34 -> 37, 37 -> 40, 
   40 -> 10, 10 -> 12, 12 -> 14, 14 -> 16, 16 -> 18, 18 -> 23, 
   23 -> 26, 26 -> 29, 29 -> 32, 32 -> 37, 37 -> 39, 39 -> 1, 1 -> 3, 
   3 -> 5, 5 -> 15, 15 -> 18, 18 -> 21, 21 -> 24, 24 -> 27, 27 -> 30, 
   30 -> 40, 40 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 6, 6 -> 8, 8 -> 13, 13 -> 16, 
   16 -> 19, 19 -> 22, 22 -> 27, 27 -> 29, 29 -> 31, 31 -> 33, 
   33 -> 35, 35 -> 5};
gr = GraphPlot3D[data, Method -> "SpringEmbedding"]
coordinates = gr[[1, 1]]
edges = gr[[1, 2, 1, 2, 1]]
```

Output:

[image]

```
{{2.15099, 1.18307, 3.11637}, {3.04554, 0.934916, 2.56025}, {3.55454, 
  1.21541, 1.90224}, {3.64482, 1.99867, 1.19894}, {3.2115, 2.38972, 
  0.549773}, {2.28274, 2.36187, 0.00260647}, {1.28767, 2.28706, 
  0.00272485}, {0.379458, 2.18177, 0.552232}, {0., 1.64516, 
  1.20573}, {0.226403, 0.985251, 1.912}, {0.946206, 0.603301, 
  2.56797}, {1.83231, 0.329511, 2.56276}, {2.65923, 0.220807, 
  1.90275}, {3.17392, 0.63046, 1.19994}, {3.26151, 1.46478, 
  0.547847}, {3.0135, 3.17375, 1.21467}, {2.42955, 3.54417, 
  1.92239}, {1.82077, 3.30175, 2.57303}, {1.50578, 2.44273, 
  3.11857}, {1.19737, 1.49462, 3.11698}, {1.21934, 0.0929668, 
  1.91297}, {1.99693, 0., 1.20222}, {2.38452, 0.434066, 
  0.545737}, {2.3541, 1.36368, 0.}, {2.18052, 3.26543, 
  0.558385}, {1.64804, 3.64083, 1.21331}, {0.991134, 3.41471, 
  1.91654}, {0.612497, 2.69602, 2.57153}, {0.339418, 1.81279, 
  2.56705}, {0.632563, 0.468973, 1.20897}, {1.46275, 0.38174, 
  0.550977}, {3.31226, 1.81971, 2.56268}, {2.45549, 2.13245, 
  3.11539}, {0.0986677, 2.42307, 1.91563}, {0.434602, 1.25784, 
  0.551964}, {1.36011, 1.29101, 0.00233058}, {3.42145, 2.65132, 
  1.9113}, {2.70536, 3.02741, 2.57249}, {0.471524, 3.01036, 
  1.21356}, {1.25737, 3.2109, 0.556519}}

{{1,2},{1,12},{1,20},{1,33},{2,3},{2,13},{2,32},{3,4},{3,14},{3,32},{4,5},{4,15},{4,37},{5,6},{5,15},{5,16},{6,7},{6,24},{6,25},{7,8},{7,36},{7,40},{8,9},{8,35},{8,39},{9,10},{9,34},{9,35},{10,11},{10,29},{10,30},{11,12},{11,20},{11,21},{12,13},{12,21},{13,14},{13,22},{14,15},{14,23},{15,24},{16,17},{16,25},{16,37},{17,18},{17,26},{17,38},{18,19},{18,27},{18,38},{19,20},{19,28},{19,33},{20,29},{21,22},{21,30},{22,23},{22,31},{23,24},{23,31},{24,36},{25,26},{25,40},{26,27},{26,40},{27,28},{27,39},{28,29},{28,34},{29,34},{30,31},{30,35},{31,36},{32,33},{32,37},{33,38},{34,39},{35,36},{37,38},{39,40}}
```

Now you can see that order of the edges that was in my original `data` is different in output `edges`.
But I need to know what coordinates belong to what point. For example what are coordinates of end points of my edge `5->8`?

**I consider it to be a bug, that the order of edges was nor preserved**, otherwise I would be able to identify coordinate of each point/edge.
Is there some way to do it automatically? I can do it manually but that is very time consuming.

**EDIT 1:**
Maybe I accepted flinty's answer too early or I am doing something wrong but the points still does not seem to be ordered correctly.

Try the following code which highlights edge `5->8` and also plots points `5` and `8` according to their coordinates. But the highlighted edge does not correspond to these points:

```
gr = Graph3D[data, GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding"]
Show[{HighlightGraph[gr, 5 -> 8], 
  Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.05], Point[GraphEmbedding[gr][[{5, 8}]]]}]}]
```

Output:

[image]

So did I do something wrong or I am right that the Mathematica's ordering is wrong?

**EDIT 2:**
Problem in "edit 1" is resolved with `VertexList[gr]` as flinty explains in his comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't get your coordinates out of a `GraphPlot3D` like this. Instead, construct the graph with

```
gr = Graph3D[data, GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding"]
```

The edges are then ordered properly in `EdgeList[gr]`:

```
EdgeList[gr] == (data /. Rule -> DirectedEdge)
(* result: True *)
```

... and the vertex coordinates from the layout are in
`GraphEmbedding[gr]`

However, the coordinates obtained through `GraphEmbedding` will not be ordered as vertex 1, vertex 2, vertex 3, ..., vertex n, but will be ordered according to `VertexList[gr]`. We can get the position of a vertex in the `VertexList` like this: `VertexIndex[gr, 5]`.

So to get the coordinates in the order you want we do a permutation:

```
Part[GraphEmbedding[gr], Ordering[VertexList[gr]]]
```

You can check individual coordinates too. In this example we get the coordinates associated with vertex 5: `AnnotationValue[{gr, 5}, VertexCoordinates]`.

Comment: Are `GraphPlot3D` and `Graph3D` plots identical? They do not seem to be identical, as the coordinates are different. Why is it so? The method is same in both cases i.e. `"SpringEmbedding"`.

Comment: They are not identical. `GraphPlot3D` probably has a different number of iterations and some different settings because its purpose is presentation. Perhaps look at experimenting with this number: `GraphLayout -> {"SpringEmbedding", "MaxIteration" -> 50}`

Comment: I mean if we apply rotation and scaling of first plot can we get it exactly same as the second plot?

Comment: Possibly. Why is it important that it's exactly the same as `GraphPlot3D`? You can always do all your layout in `Graph3D` and then pass it to `GraphPlot3D` if you want more styling, without affecting the layout.

Comment: The purpose of selecting method should be that if we choose particular method we should get exactly the same result, except rotation and scaling can be different. But I do not see a reason to use a different rotation/scaling in `GraphPlot3D` and different `Graph3D`. And still I am not sure they are identical neglecting rotation/scaling.

Comment: `GraphPlot3D` is different because it's trying to display the vertices and edges - it's purpose is display only and this could mean rotating or translating the vertices under the hood to fit the view. I must admit, I don't know for certain, I think the reason for the implementation difference is one for Wolfram as I'm just speculating.

Comment: Nevermind, you answered my original question. Why `GraphPlot3D` and `Graph3D` do not produce plots with identical coordinates of points is another question...

Comment: Sorry, but can you look at my question again? ... I made an edit to it and also I canceled my acceptation of your answer for now. Maybe I am doing something wrong but the ordering does not seem to be correct for me.

Comment: @azerbajdzan vertices {5,8} don't occur at *position* {5,8} in the `VertexList[gr]`. They appear at positions {1,2}. Get them with `pos = Flatten[Position[VertexList[gr], 5 | 8]]` then you can do `Point[GraphEmbedding[gr][[pos]]]`

Comment: Ahh I see... but I do not understand why ordering of points in `VertexList[gr]` should be different than in `GraphEmbedding`. But again nevermind... I reaccepted your answer ;-)

Comment: There's also `VertexIndex` and you can do `VertexIndex[gr,{5,8}]`. There's a distinction between the node value / label and the position which is causing confusion here, and that's the reason for the reordering - so that Mathematica can store non-numeric nodes that don't have a natural sorting order.