# Algorithms used in GraphPlot and GraphPlot3D

Tags: graphs-and-networks, graphics3d

Coppied from Mathematica's help:

> Algorithms to be used in GraphPlot and GraphPlot3D can be specified
> using the Method option, either as Method->"name" or
> Method->{"name",Subscript[opt, 1]->Subscript[val, 1],[Ellipsis]},
> where Subscript[opt, i]-> Subscript[val, i] are method-specific
> options, described in separate sections.

> "SpringElectricalEmbedding"   invoke the spring-electrical embedding
> method, in which neighboring vertices are subject to an attractive
> spring force that is proportional to their physical distance, and all
> vertices are subject to a repulsive electrical force that is inversely
> proportional to their distance; the overall energy is minimized

> "SpringEmbedding" invoke the spring embedding method, in which a
> vertex is subject to either attractive or repulsive force from another
> vertex, as though they are connected by a spring; the spring has an
> ideal length equal to the graph distance between the vertices; the
> total spring energy is minimized

I would like to have also "ElectricalEmbedding" in which only repulsive electrical force would take place. The points of vertices could move only on the surface of unit sphere (to not allow them to go infinitely apart because of the repulsion).

**Is it possible to simulate such "ElectricalEmbedding" scenario with existing methods implemented in Mathematica or a new implementation is needed?**

PS: You can see how such graph that uses "SpringEmbedding" may look at [my other question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/225787/graphplot3d-does-not-preserve-the-order-of-points-edges-how-to-identify-coord).

Comment: If there's no attractive force, or tension in the edges, then in the limit you'll just gets points equidistributed on the sphere, i.e `SpherePoints[n]` . See this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/142113/72682

Comment: Nice. I did not know about `SpherePoints`. That is what I want but also I want to have the points to be connected like in the graph. Say first and second points make first edge of graph, second and third point make second edge and so on... `SpherePoints` only gives me positions of all points, how can I determine the edges of the graph then?

Comment: You'd use them as your vertex coordinates. `SpringElectricalEmbedding` does have options to control the "SpringConstant", which must be positive and "RepulsiveForcePower" which must be negative - however these will not restrict the points to the sphere.

Comment: So I would need something like `SpringElectricalEmbedding` or `SpringEmbedding` but with additional constraint that points are allowed to move freely only on surface of unit sphere not the entire space.

Comment: Yes, you can write down the equations of motion and solve them with `NDSolve`. However, this seems not related to graphs. In the methods you reference, electric repulsion is present between all pairs of vertices, not just connected ones.

Comment: [This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/111006/731) about how to implement a force layout may be inspiring perhaps.